# php Saop always return NULL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i am trying to make a soap API working. but i get errors. 
Following is the wsdl file.

```
https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/webservices.asmx?wsdl
```

The following is the code

```
try{
    $c = new SoapClient("https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/webservices.asmx?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
    $x = $c->GetNewTransactions(array("login" => "username", "pwd" => "password"));
    //execution fails from above line
    SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders();
 }catch(SoapFault $e){
var_dump($e);
}
```

the output $x is suppose to have a property `xmlTransactions` as per the wsdl file or atleast an `erroerror` property. What i get it actually a NULL

```
object(SoapFault)#2 (9) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(9) "Not Found"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["file":protected]=>
  string(23) "/var/www/haad/index.php"
  ["line":protected]=>
  int(6)
  ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["function"]=>
      string(11) "__doRequest"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        string(316) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetNewTransactions><ns1:login>User</ns1:login><ns1:pwd>_PASS</ns1:pwd></ns1:GetNewTransactions></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
"
        [1]=>
        string(44) "http://www.shafafiya.org/v2/webservices.asmx"
        [2]=>
        string(47) "https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/GetNewTransactions"
        [3]=>
        int(1)
        [4]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(23) "/var/www/haad/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(6)
      ["function"]=>
      string(6) "__call"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(18) "GetNewTransactions"
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["login"]=>
            string(6) "user"
            ["pwd"]=>
            string(8) "PASS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["file"]=>
      string(23) "/var/www/haad/index.php"
      ["line"]=>
      int(6)
      ["function"]=>
      string(18) "GetNewTransactions"
      ["class"]=>
      string(10) "SoapClient"
      ["type"]=>
      string(2) "->"
      ["args"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["login"]=>
          string(6) "User"
          ["pwd"]=>
          string(8) "pass"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
  NULL
  ["faultstring"]=>
  string(9) "Not Found"
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(4) "HTTP"
}
```

The api seems to work with other languages

any idea

thanks

Comment: Enable the exceptions and you'll probably see your problem (why would you _disable_ them when you're clearly having some problems?)... Or if you enable `trace`, why not see what the last raw request & response was?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in /var/www/haad/index.php:5 this is the error that i get when i enable exception... any idea what could be the fix?i am not an expert in this

Comment: It probably means it can't reach the `https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/webservices.asmx?wsdl` url. Options to try, in order: (1) is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled? (2) can you `file_get_contents($your_wsdl_url);`? If not, connection issue, if you can... wsdl syntax issue (but I doubt that) (3) you could try to set a `user_agent` (some services are picky that way) (4) if it all fails.. check with network-/sysadmins why your connection fails.

Comment: 1)allow_url_fopen is enabled, i can  get file_get_contents($wsdl_file), i do not think it is a network issue.i tried it from different network. let me try out useragent

Comment: Hm, import bit then: does the constructing of the client, or the `GetNewTransactions` throw the exception? (In case of the latter: can you access `https://www.shafafiya.org/v2/GetNewTransactions`? It may be _that_ url the misbehaves (do check the `__getLastResponseHeaders()` output).

Comment: i tried to get  SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders(); but the execution does not go beyond $x = $c->GetNewTransactions(). i did the api inside an try statement and caught the exception. I have updated my question with the that.

Comment: `var_dump(SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders());` in your `catch` block, not your `try` block.

Comment: ["__last_response_headers"]=>
  string(250) "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1514
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2013 05:44:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Comment: Hm, and what are the request headers?

Comment: i called this GetNewTransactions api and printed the header, i get 404. I tried to ping the site..ping shafafiya.org.. all packets were lost.. after loading the wdsl file all the api gets a 404 error. i have read that php soap has internal issue with proxy. will there be any proxy?

Comment: The site just disallows ICMP (pings), so not an issue there. You can _reach_ the webserver (otherwise, you won't get a 404 but a 'no connection' error), so that's not the case either. I fear there's either a failed precondition or a bug on the server side. Double check your payload (user & password), and if you know these to be correct, contact the provider of that soap service as to why they throw 404's.

Comment: Username and password are correct, infact it was working for the past 6 months, suddenly it stoped working and they blame the php code. i tried everything i knew. BIG THANKYOU for your help :)

Comment: finally got it resolved!!! WDSL has got error.. in the  wsld file the urls were http instead of https